# ¿Cómo optimizar estos for?

Tags: java, apache-poi

Estoy generando un excel a partir de una List(filas) que cada índice contiene otro list con los valores de cada celda, el caso es que hay como unas 1500 filas con unos 750 a 1000 valores cada una, y tarda 30 segundos en generar el excel, he probado actualizando las versiones de las librerías a la última versión, pero nada, estoy utilizando un workbook SXSSFWorkBook(-1).

Lo único que no he probado ha sido a usar streams o parallelStreams, pero es que éstos no pueden actuar con las variables de fuera.

Gracias de antemano.

```
int cellnum;
    SXSSFCell cell;
    for (List<String> fileValues : filas) {
        row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
        cellnum = 0;

        for (String valor : fileValues) {
            cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
            if (StringUtils.isNumeric(valor)) {
                cell.setCellValue(Integer.parseInt(valor));
                cell.setCellStyle(estiloFilas);
            } else if (IncFuncionesPlx.isHoraValida(valor, sdf)) {
                cell.setCellValue(IncFuncionesPlx.tiempoASegundosSinComprobacion(valor) / 86400);
                cell.setCellStyle(formatoHoras);
            } else {
                cell.setCellValue(valor);
                cell.setCellStyle(estiloFilas);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: El proceso de los dos fors conlleva mucho tiempo, se podría cambiar, o posicionar esos list para un acceso más rápido, o no hay forma de tratar esta cantidad ingente de datos de una manera más eficaz?

Comment: Si realmente necesitas esos datos en ese formato es inevitable hacer el doble bucle deberás sufrir el *O(nxm)*. Pero puedes probar una aproximación diferente: [Programación orientada a datos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programación_dirigida_por_datos). 1) Genera todas las celdas 2) Aplica formato. Dime si notas alguna mejora de rendimiento.

Comment: Estás generando una hoja de cálculo con aproximadamente `1500 * 800` valores, eso significa alrededor de 1.200.000 celdas... varios megabytes. Directamente me sorprende que Excel pueda abrir el fichero. El código lo veo correcto, estás reutilizando los estilos aplicados a las celdas. Sencillamente son muchos datos y va a tardar en generarse. Quizá generar un CSV sería menos costoso, dejando a Excel interpretar los datos al abrirlo.

Comment: Podrias utlizar 4 hilos o mas para optimizar esos for que tienes y poner ese mismo cidigo en un hilo con las 4 ejecuciones que te menciono para que lo guarde mucho mas rapido.

Comment: ¿Si generas el Excel sin los `if` va rápido? Coincido con @PabloLozano en que quizá lo más simple para este caso sería generar un `.csv` y luego mandárselo a Excel para crear la hoja de datos. Aún así, es cuestionable un requerimiento de `1500 * 800`. ¿No será necesario replantearse la lógica en que se quiere hacer funcionar tu aplicación? ¿Quién va a a analizar un archivo tan grande? Incluso en el mismo Excel podría ser un gran dolor de cabeza moverse dentro del monstruo que se está generando. Por algo existen los filtros, los grupos, los detalles...

Comment: Vale, comentaros que los for´s solo tardan 4 segundos en recorrerse, el problema no está ahí, el problema está en un resultSet que se recorre anteriormente para preparar esos List (while(rs.next()) y ahí demora 20 segundos, en producción no tienen 1500 filas sino 3000 pero solo 7 columnas, decir que el Excel abre perfectamente el archivo y se mueve con "soltura", ahora estoy buscando para optimizar ese resultSet, gracias a todos, lo que aún no probé fue lo de programar con hilos, que es algo nuevo para mi.